# Applying condition on section numbers in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one column has values like so:

```
Section
1.0
1.0.1
1.1
1.2

2.0
2.0.1
2.1

3.0
3.1
...
```

I'd like to filter the dataframe so that only the "major" headings are chosen (i.e. 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, and so on).

My code:

```
def filter_for_pointNull_Sections(self, df):
    if len(df['Section'].str.split(".")) < 3 and df['Section'].str.split(".")[1] == 0:
        df['Section_BOOL'] = True
    else:
        df['Section_BOOL'] = False

    return df
```

I'm sure this is not the most pythonic way, and it's wrong as somehow all values returned are False.

Actually my initial aim was to produce the new "Section_BOOL" column, then filter on True. But instead this can be bypassed directly I believe.

How can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare values converted to numeric if integers are same like floats:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df['Section'], errors='coerce')

df['Section_BOOL'] = s.fillna(0).astype(int).eq(s)
print (df)
  Section  Section_BOOL
0     1.0          True
1   1.0.1         False
2     1.1         False
3     1.2         False
4     2.0          True
5   2.0.1         False
6     2.1         False
7     3.0          True
8     3.1         False
```

Another idea:

```
df['Section_BOOL'] = df['Section'].str.endswith('0') & df['Section'].str.count('\.').eq(1)
print (df)
  Section  Section_BOOL
0     1.0          True
1   1.0.1         False
2     1.1         False
3     1.2         False
4     2.0          True
5   2.0.1         False
6     2.1         False
7     3.0          True
8     3.1         False
```

Comment: the first solution worked completely - thank you! I didn't quite understand however what is happening in "s.fillna(0).astype(int).eq(s)".

Comment: @pymat - I first convert values to numeric, if possible by `pd.to_numeric(df['Section'], errors='coerce')`, then replace `NaN` to `0` and convert to integers and last compare by numeric values in `s` - so get only rows like `integers with `.0`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can test if the section ends with `.0`:

```
df['Section_BOOL'] = df['Section'].str.endswith('.0')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Section  Section_BOOL
0     1.0          True
1   1.0.1         False
2     1.1         False
3     1.2         False
4     2.0          True
5   2.0.1         False
6     2.1         False
7     3.0          True
8     3.1         False
```

Answer (score 0):

The key info is the blank line (which I'll assume is a NaN)

```
def get_headings(df):
    padding = pd.DataFrame(index=[1])
    ans = (df
     .append(padding) # Add 2 blank lines at the bottom
     .shift(1) # Shift all values down 1, adding a NaN line above the fisrt row
     .loc[lambda x: x['Section'].shift(1).replace('',np.nan).isna()] # Select rows where the row above is NaN, treating '' as NaN
     .shift(-1) # shift up by one
     .iloc[:-1] # drop the padding
     )
    return ans
```

Let me know if this works.